# Using SSIS, SQL Server to import into a custom Sharepoint List

Tags: sql-server-2008, sharepoint, ssis

currently I'm using an OLE DB Source (SQL Server) to insert records into a SharePoint List Destination.

This is all working fine and the result I was looking for was to insert a list of people into a people picker field, which I achieved by using the User ID's from the User Information List in SharePoint.

The problem is, that now I want to insert multiple people, into one multiple choice people picker field, I've tried separating the User ID's in the table with a semi-colon and several other methods, but it just returns an error and doesn't write that row.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by using a workflow to insert email addresses separated by semi-colons into the people picker field